# Calculate total time worked in a day with multiple stops and starts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can use DATEDIFF to find the difference between one set of dates like this

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startdate, @enddate)
```

but how would I find the total time span between multiple sets of dates? I don't know how many sets (stops and starts) I will have.

The data is on multiple rows with start and stops.

```
ID     TimeStamp                StartOrStop        TimeCode
----------------------------------------------------------------
1      2017-01-01 07:00:00      Start              1
2      2017-01-01 08:15:00      Stop               2
3      2017-01-01 10:00:00      Start              1
4      2017-01-01 11:00:00      Stop               2 
5      2017-01-01 10:30:00      Start              1
6      2017-01-01 12:00:00      Stop               2
```

Comment: `select sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startdate, @enddate))....`

Comment: Is it one row with a start/stop per record, or start stop across two rows? If you could provide sample data this would be a lot easier.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - I would have thought `select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min(startdate), max(enddate))` would be more efficient?

Comment: @Tony It depends on his data, since he mentioned "multiples stops and starts" your solution would sum also the intervals between an stop and a start what seems to not comply with what he wants.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - you are correct. I wasn't thinking straight :)

Comment: @Tony Now that he showed his data none of our solution would work :P

Answer (score 1):

This code would work assuming that your table only store data from one person, and they should be of the order Start/Stop/Start/Stop

```
WITH StartTime AS (
SELECT
    TimeStamp
    , ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY (ORDER BY TimeStamp) RowNum
FROM
    <<table>>
WHERE
    TimeCode = 1
), StopTime AS (
SELECT
    TimeStamp
    , ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY (ORDER BY TimeStamp) RowNum
FROM
    <<table>>
WHERE
    TimeCode = 2
)
SELECT
    SUM (DATEDIFF( MINUTE, StartTime.TimeStamp, StopTime.TimeStamp )) As TotalTime
FROM
    StartTime
    JOIN StopTime ON StartTime.RowNum = StopTime.RowNum
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work if your starts and stops are reliable.  Your sample has two starts in order - 10:00 and 10:30 starts.  I assume in production you will have an employee id to group on, so I added this to the sample data in place of the identity column.

Also in production, the CTE sets will be reduced by using a parameter on date.  If there are overnight shifts, you would want your `stops` CTE to use `dateadd(day, 1, @startDate)` as your upper bound when retrieving end date.

**Set up sample:**

```
declare @temp table (
    EmpId int,
    TimeStamp datetime,
    StartOrStop varchar(55),
    TimeCode int
);

insert into @temp 
values
(1, '2017-01-01 07:00:00', 'Start', 1),
(1, '2017-01-01 08:15:00', 'Stop', 2),
(1, '2017-01-01 10:00:00', 'Start', 1),
(1, '2017-01-01 11:00:00', 'Stop', 2),
(2, '2017-01-01 10:30:00', 'Start', 1),
(2, '2017-01-01 12:00:00', 'Stop', 2)
```

**Query:**

```
;with starts as (
    select  t.EmpId, 
            t.TimeStamp as StartTime,
            row_number() over (partition by t.EmpId order by t.TimeStamp asc) as rn
    from @temp t 
    where Timecode = 1 --Start time code?
),
stops as (
    select  t.EmpId, 
            t.TimeStamp as EndTime,
            row_number() over (partition by t.EmpId order by t.TimeStamp asc) as rn
    from @temp t 
    where Timecode = 2 --Stop time code?
)

select  cast(min(sub.StartTime) as date) as WorkDay, 
        sub.EmpId as Employee,
        min(sub.StartTime) as ClockIn,
        min(sub.EndTime) as ClockOut,
        sum(sub.MinutesWorked) as MinutesWorked
from 
(
    select  strt.EmpId,
            strt.StartTime, 
            stp.EndTime,
            datediff(minute, strt.StartTime, stp.EndTime) as MinutesWorked
    from starts strt
    inner join stops stp
        on strt.EmpId = stp.EmpId 
        and strt.rn = stp.rn
)sub
group by sub.EmpId
```

Answer (score 1):

This works assuming your table has an incremental `ID` and interleaving start/stop records

```
--Data sample as provided

declare @temp table (
    Id int,
    TimeStamp datetime,
    StartOrStop varchar(55),
    TimeCode int
);

insert into @temp 
values
(1, '2017-01-01 07:00:00', 'Start', 1),
(2, '2017-01-01 08:15:00', 'Stop', 2),
(3, '2017-01-01 10:00:00', 'Start', 1),
(4, '2017-01-01 11:00:00', 'Stop', 2),
(5, '2017-01-01 10:30:00', 'Start', 1),
(6, '2017-01-01 12:00:00', 'Stop', 2)


--let's see every pair start/stop and discard stop/start

select start.timestamp start, stop.timestamp stop, 
    datediff(mi,start.timestamp,stop.timestamp) minutes
from @temp start inner join @temp stop 
    on start.id+1= stop.id and start.timecode=1

--Sum all for required result

select sum(datediff(mi,start.timestamp,stop.timestamp) ) totalMinutes
from @temp start inner join @temp stop 
    on start.id+1= stop.id and start.timecode=1
```

Results

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
|          start          |          stop           | minutes |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 2017-01-01 07:00:00.000 | 2017-01-01 08:15:00.000 |      75 |
| 2017-01-01 10:00:00.000 | 2017-01-01 11:00:00.000 |      60 |
| 2017-01-01 10:30:00.000 | 2017-01-01 12:00:00.000 |      90 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+

+--------------+
| totalMinutes |
+--------------+
|          225 |
+--------------+
```

Maybe the tricky part is the `join` clause. We need to join `@table` with itself by deferring 1 `ID`. Here is where `on start.id+1= stop.id` did its work.

In the other hand, for excluding stop/start couple we use `start.timecode=1`. In case we don't have a column with this information, something like `stop.id%2=0` works just fine.

Comment: @PtotheBZZ have you check this solution? let me know if you need forward assistance